# How to call an API on one server from a User-interface (Webpage) on a different server?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, web

I want to separate my API, which basically queries Azure tables and returns objects representing entries in the Azure table, from the webpage that calls the API on button clicks. Basically, I want the two things to be on separate servers. I don't have any experience doing this, any idea how to approach this? Am I conceptually wrong here somewhere?

Just as an example, say the API is on a server "foreignserver" has a function:

```
public string double(string x)
{
    return x + x + ".";
}
```

and I want to call this function from my localhost on a asp.net page button click:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   string y = //Connect to other server and call API? ;
}
```

Just to clarify, I am basically trying to decouple the front-end from the API by putting each on separate servers.

Comment: What is your API (on foreignserver) that you'll be calling built with? Web API? WCF? Custom?

Comment: It is a REST-based API which basically has get functions that return values from an Azure storage table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am basically trying to decouple the front-end from the API by putting each on separate servers

Seems like a reasonable concept to me, there are tons of reasons why this is a good idea like if you intend on opening up your API for public use or sharing it across multiple sites.

In order to do what you are doing you simply need to make a web request from your website to your API e.g.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var request = WebRequest.Create("http://foreignserver/api/..."))
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        string y = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The "/..." would be what in the example I provided? Can I just directly call that function and get the string it returns?

Comment: @SKLAK `/...` would be the path to your API call. If you don't already have an API or don't know how to build one, I'd recommend [MVC Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: can the view be separated to a diff server for a MVC Web API?

Comment: thank you.. I just adapted my API to work as an MVC Web API and so far so good, I am able to call it from different hosts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something ilke this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   string y = new WebClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/api/Double?x=5");
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to use the correct address.